# Google + won't let me see my photos, they ask me to upgrade safari

Tags: snow-leopard, google

Google + won't let me see my photos, they ask me to upgrade safari. 
My Safari update is ok  I have MacPro Book OS x  10.6.8

Answer (score 4):

The only way to update Safari is to update your OS. I would try opening Google+ in Chrome which has been updated for 10.6 more recently than Safari.